# How to create .pfx file from sslopenfree 3 files output?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I know there are other similar Q/A about this but they are somewhat confusing and do not help solving my question.

I got a certificate from [sslforfree](https://www.sslforfree.com): zip output contains 3 files:

1. ca_bundle.crt
2. certificate.crt
3. private.key

As I need to provide my maintainer with a .pfx certificate, I installed OpenSSL and tried to follow some hints on this and other forums.
The command line should be:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.name.pfx -inkey domain.name.key -in domain.name.crt
```

OR

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.name.pfx -inkey domain.name.key -in domain.name.crt -in intermediate.crt -in rootca.crt
```

It's not clear to me:

1. what does "domain.name" refers to, for even if I typed my domain's
   name in creating the certificate, none of the 3 received files
   contains a visible reference to it.
2. should I use ca_bundle.crt or certificate.crt in creating the .pfx ?

Could someone please give me a plain command line example, given above received files' names?

Answer (score 1):

It came out that trying to use "ca_bundle.crt" resulted in a command line verbose error output, so I switched to "certificate.crt" and it worked just fine. Again, I have no idea what the "ca-bundle.crt" file is for, but it looked totally useless for my present needs.

Given input files the command line used was:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out xyzdomain.com.pfx -inkey private.key -in certificate.crt
```

and the exported .pfx was subsequently successfully installed.

Answer (score 1):

The command which you have found is exactly correct I will just reframe you the code as per your file names

1) **ca_bundle.crt**
2) **certificate.crt**
3) **private.key**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out filename.pfx -inkey private.key -in certificate.crt -in ca_bundle.crt
```

As you have **ca_bundle.crt** you don't need to insert 
 `-in intermediate.crt -in rootca.crt` 
commands in OpenSSL since it contains both intermediate and root

Else you can check out the alternate way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701821/how-to-install-a-ssl-sertificate-from-diffrent-server-to-my-server/46703375#46703375)

In the second command
    `OpenSSL pkcs12 -export -out xyzdomain.com.pfx -inkey private.key -in certificate.crt`,
 you have not used the intermediate and root so you will get an error of intermediate missing on any SSL checker

If you get error while importing **ca-bundle.crt**, you need to ask your vendor to provide the correct bundle certificate file