# How to install a ssl sertificate from diffrent server to my server,

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I want to create a website in my IIS server, (website already has ssl certificate).
So i created a site, I have the certificate details which contains certificate, private key , CA certificate (all in one text file).

I havent created a csr request for this, But i need to install this certififcate in my system.

When i followed the steps in complete cerififcate request, first it got added, but when i refresh and came back it was gone.

Please help me how to install certififcate from other server, without creating csr request.?

i have:
1)Certificate:
2)Private key (*.key)
3)CA certificate (*-ca.crt)

in the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the text file into *.pfx file so that you can import it on IIS

**Open the .key via notepad copy the content and save it in a new notepad say abc.txt**

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQDJl/Dwe2tzd5Z6
L4fWpUDVP6FDE9Tc0ViHlICsopxPumysltLwuLFCsc9gCOOURc6n0ej2XQoBJeuetqTIRZQ3VOlHqcmxdBTaAxw5iQ==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

**Now open the certificate via notepad copy the content and paste it in the same abc.txt notepad**

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIG5jCCBc6gAwIBAgIQUERflom9AJ4ssjDKLPM3SDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBB
bS9jcHMwLwYIKwYBBQUHAgIwIwwhaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhhd3RlLmNvbS9yZXBv
SzBJMB8GCCsGAQUFBzABhhNodHRwOi8vdGouc3ltY2QuY29tMCYGCCsGAQUFBzAC
B7MDaIXp7iniBRfFT3MOMm2Bs3Mju2Hwfhrgg7sf96iQzZkzAU6Mxdux
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Open the -ca.crt via notepad copy the content and paste it in the same abc.txt file (this file will contain intermediate and root certificates)

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIG5jCCBc6gAwIBAgIQUERflom9AJ4ssjDKLPM3SDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBB
bS9jcHMwLwYIKwYBBQUHAgIwIwwhaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhhd3RlLmNvbS9yZXBv
SzBJMB8GCCsGAQUFBzABhhNodHRwOi8vdGouc3ltY2QuY29tMCYGCCsGAQUFBzAC
B7MDaIXp7iniBRfFT3MOMm2Bs3Mju2Hwfhrgg7sf96iQzZkzAU6Mxdux
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEIDCCAwigAwIBAgIQNE7VVyDV7exJ9C/ON9srbTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
qTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDHRoYXd0ZSwgSW5jLjEoMCYGA1UECxMf
/qxAeeWsEG89jxt5dovEN7MhGITlNgDrYyCZuen+MwS7QcjBAvlEYyCegc5C09Y/
LHbTY5xZ3Y+m4Q6gLkH3LpVHz7z9M/P2C2F+fpErgUfCJzDupxBdN49cOSvkBPB7
jVaMaA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

**At the end, your abc.txt file will have something like this**

*-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----*
MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQDJl/Dwe2tzd5Z6
L4fWpUDVP6FDE9Tc0ViHlICsopxPumysltLwuLFCsc9gCOOURc6n0ej2XQoBJeue
tqTIRZQ3VOlHqcmxdBTaAxw5iQ==
*-----END PRIVATE KEY-----*
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIG5jCCBc6gAwIBAgIQUERflom9AJ4ssjDKLPM3SDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBB
bS9jcHMwLwYIKwYBBQUHAgIwIwwhaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhhd3RlLmNvbS9yZXBv
SzBJMB8GCCsGAQUFBzABhhNodHRwOi8vdGouc3ltY2QuY29tMCYGCCsGAQUFBzAC
B7MDaIXp7iniBRfFT3MOMm2Bs3Mju2Hwfhrgg7sf96iQzZkzAU6Mxdux
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
*-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----*
MIIG5jCCBc6gAwIBAgIQUERflom9AJ4ssjDKLPM3SDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBB
bS9jcHMwLwYIKwYBBQUHAgIwIwwhaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhhd3RlLmNvbS9yZXBv
SzBJMB8GCCsGAQUFBzABhhNodHRwOi8vdGouc3ltY2QuY29tMCYGCCsGAQUFBzAC
B7MDaIXp7iniBRfFT3MOMm2Bs3Mju2Hwfhrgg7sf96iQzZkzAU6Mxdux
*-----END CERTIFICATE-----*
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEIDCCAwigAwIBAgIQNE7VVyDV7exJ9C/ON9srbTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
qTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDHRoYXd0ZSwgSW5jLjEoMCYGA1UECxMf
/qxAeeWsEG89jxt5dovEN7MhGITlNgDrYyCZuen+MwS7QcjBAvlEYyCegc5C09Y/
LHbTY5xZ3Y+m4Q6gLkH3LpVHz7z9M/P2C2F+fpErgUfCJzDupxBdN49cOSvkBPB7
jVaMaA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Download OpenSSL from [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads)
Ones installed copy the abc.txt and paste it in the bin path of OpenSSL **(e.g. C:\OpenSSL\bin)**

Open the CMD, change directory to the bin folder of OpenSSL and paste the below command in CMD

**openssl pkcs12 -export -in abc.txt -out xyz.pfx**

give any password

You can use the xyz.pfx to import on IIS by using the same set of password

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with just built-in tool `certutil.exe` which is shipped with every Windows installation.

1. make sure SSL certificate file and private key file are stored in the same folder and have same name: `mycert.cer` and `mycert.key`, for example. Certificate will have `.cer` file extension, key file will have `.key` file extension.
2. run the following command: `certutil -mergepfx path\mycert.cer path\mycert.pfx`

this command will merge SSL certificate and private key into PFX container. Enter password when prompted.

Comment: I just ran this and it place the file in the c:\Windows\System32 directory regardless as to what I specified for path in the second parameter.  
I will add though it worked when importing into IIS!  Thank  you Crypt32